# Initializing an instance of my model giving me <<error type>>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is my class

```
struct Card {
var isFaceUp = false
var isMatched = false
var identifier: Int

}
```

When I try to initialize my class it returns <> in Xcode when I try to initialize my let card = Cards(<-should autofill but spits errors.

```
class Stanford {
var cards = [Card]()

func chooseCard(at index: Int){
let card = Card(
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine, clean and build your project again, dont loose any closing braces.

Comment: Is the the question about Xcode autofill not suggesting the right thing or is there code missing in `chooseCard`?

Comment: If autofill doesn't work then maybe you have some other syntax error on your code, autofill worked fine for me with your code using a playground.